# AD Cyclic Group Remediation using powershell script

Tags: powershell, group

I am working on cyclic AD group remediation using powershell script(new to the powershell). The logic would be something like below-

```
For each Grp in the List
    For Each Parent in Child MemberOf
        Add Child Members (both users and groups) to Parent (check to see if already a Member first before adding to Parent)
        Remove Child from Parent Member (will also reflect as being removed from Child's MemberOf)
    End For
End For
```

To illustrate with the example-

[image: Algo Dry run]

The input to the script will be from the CSV file. After remediation, the Effective Access (Pre) = Direct Access (Post).
Can anyone help me with powershell code here?

Appreciate the help.

Comment: This site works best when you have a specific and targeted question about an error or problem with code you've already written - if you can post some code that you have problems with you're more likely to get help than asking "help me write this program" - see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Your question as it stands is likely to attract votes to close unless you can add some code and explain what part isn't working how you expect it to...